# how to do authentication using cookies in expo app

Tags: axios, expo

I am working on an expo app and the APIs for the app using session and cookies for authentication can anybody help me or guide me on how can I do auth using expo. I have never done that But the person for whom I am working said you have to use cookies. I am using Axios for making requests. please guide me is it possible and if yes then how can I get cookies after login req and how to make the next requests by sending automatic cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you want but looks like you want to store auth token to localstorage or something. so in that case you can us AsyncStorage.

Docs: [here.](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v40.0.0/sdk/async-storage/)